# How to configure eclipse to access an endpoint over the SSL protocol?

Tags: eclipse, rest, ssl, ssl-certificate

When I access EndPoint within Google Chrome I get a response. Can you see in picture below:

[image]

When I try to access EndPoint from within eclipse. The following error occurs:

[image]

I configured the EndPoint certificate in eclipse. As shown in the figure below:

[image]

Is there another configuration needed to access the Endpoint within eclipse?

Comment: The server is returning an error response when you use eclipse, so it is making the connection. What you see is not what the server returned though. Find out how to make it show the response you get instead of that generic unhelpful "user friendly" error page. If it's the same error as in chrome, you need to change the user agent header like it says.

Comment: I'm try send request for RESTfull API with OKHttp client over SSL protocol but I get Timeout Exception into eclipse in my App.

Comment: Add your code and the full error message (with stack trace) to the question. What you're showing (http 400) is not a time out. Also add the appropriate tags, from the mention of okhttp I take you're working with Java and Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Internet proxy was not configured in eclipse.
After configuring the proxy in eclipse it worked perfectly.

thanks :D